# Two JavaScript functions onsubmit and onclick

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript functions to check two fields (input title and textarea)

- `form name="myform" onsubmit="return Checkthis()"`
- `button type="submit" onclick="Checkthis();return false;"`

Inside `Checkthis()` I call `Check1()` and `Check2()` and in `onsumbit=`/`onclick=`. I call only on `Checkthis()`

However, only the first function is checked `onsubmit` and `onclick`; I have tried to remove `Checkthis()` and call two functions like `onClick="Check1();Check2();"` but this doesn't work either.

```js
function Check1() {
    var msg_area = document.getElementById("mydiv1"); 

    if () { 

        return false; 
    }  
}

function Check2() {
    var msg_areaa = document.getElementById("mydiv2"); 

    if () { 

        return false; 
    }  
}

function Checkthis() {
    Check1();
    Check2();
}
```

I have tried with: `onsubmit ="Checkthis()"` and `onsubmit="return (Check1() && Check2());"`

Any method I use only the first function is checked!

Comment: One possible issue I see immediately is that you're submitting the form twice. In `Check1` and `Check2`'s else block just return true and let `Checkthis` do the submission by comparing `Check1() && Check2()`.  There's also a typo in the last code block. Not sure if it's intentional but you have `onsubmit="Chec[k]this()"`.

Comment: Suggest to replace else document.getElementById("myform").submit();  with else return true; ??? thx!

Comment: onsubmit="Checkthis();"functions not Check(this);

Comment: can you paste your actual full code for the 3 functions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay this might not be a popular answer, so downvote away, but it will probably work.

Use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#wtvrDiv").click(function(){
         Check1();
         Check2();
    });    
});
```

Comment: This is not a solution...i have two different div!

Answer (score 0):

To better explain my comments, give this a shot.

**HTML**:

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" id="titleID" />
    <input type="text" id="textareaID" />
    <button type="button" onclick="checkthis()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var check1 = function () {...} // Don't submit, just see if it's valid
var check2 = function () {...} // Don't submit, just see if it's valid

var checkthis = function() {
    if (check1 && check2) {
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    }
}
```

This page is also very helpful for getting started with [form validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp).